# How to set up pagination url to be able to use url rewriting using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

My current pagination code looks like this

```
//what page are we currently on
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=1;
    }
    else {
        $page=(int)$_GET['page'];
    }
//select how many records to show per page
$limit=10;
//count how many rows 
$total=$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagi")->fetchColumn();
//how many pages will be there
$pages=ceil($total/$limit);
if($page<1){
    $page=1;//forcing page to be 1 if it is less then 1
    }   
else if($page>$pages){
    $page=$pages;
    }
//calculate the offset 
$offset=($page-1)*$limit;
//fetch the result from database
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagi ORDER BY pg_id LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}");
$sql->execute();
if($sql->rowCount()>0){
while($result=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){;
echo $result['pg_name'],"<br />";   
}
echo "<hr>";
}else {
    echo "no result to fetch";
}   

$prev=$page-1;
$next=$page+1;
$previous="";
$nextr="";
if($page>1){
$previous='<li><a href="?page='.$prev.'">«</a></span>';
}
//for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++){
//  echo'<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
//  }
if($page<$pages){
$nextr='<li><a href="?page='.$next.'">»</a></span>';
}
$numbers="";
for($i = max(1, $page - 5); $i <= min($page + 5, $pages); $i++){
    if($i==$page){
    $numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
    }
    else {
        $numbers.='<li><a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
    }
    }
```

**And my current url look like this** :- `localhost/test/pagi.php?page=1`

`I want it to be` `localhost/test/pagi.php/page/1`

I have this following in my `.htaccess`

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ pagi.php?page=$1`

How can i change my pagination to work with above rewrite rule or maybe another rules; I want to be able to achieve when a user click on next it should redirect 
them to `pagi.php/page/123` not to `pagi.php?page=1`.I am pretty new to php and cant figure out a way to do this.Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need a new way to get the page number, since `$_GET` will no longer work with semantic urls. Something like this:

```
// find the page number, or default to page 1
$page = 1;
$path = explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
if (is_array($path) && !empty($path)) {
    if ($key = array_search('page', $path)) {
        $page = (int)$path[$key + 1];
    }
}
```

As for the pagination, you can simply wrap that into a function. The following function, for example, assumes that the page will always be specified at the very end of the url:

```
// draws a menu for navigating multiple pages of dynamic content
function paginate($page, $display, $total) {
    $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if ($path != '/') {
        $path = rtrim($path, '/');
        if (stristr($path, 'page/')) {
            $path = rtrim($path, '0..9');
            $query = '';
        } else {
            $query = $path . '/page/';
        }
    } else {
        $query = 'page/';
    }

    // create navigation links
    $pages = $total <= $display ? 1 : ceil($total / $display);
    $first = '<a href="' . $path . $query. '1">first</a>';
    $prev = '<a href="' . $path . $query . ($page - 1) . '">prev</a>';
    $next = '<a href="' . $path . $query . ($page + 1) . '">next</a>';
    $last = '<a href="' . $path . $query . $pages . '">last</a>';

    echo ($page > 1) ? "$first &#171; $prev &#171;" : 'first &#171; prev &#171;';
    echo ' (page ' . $page . ' of ' . $pages . ') ';
    echo ($page < $pages) ? "&#187; $next &#187; $last" : '&#187; next &#187; last';
}
```

Based on your example code, it should end up looking something like this:

```
// find the page number, or default to page 1
// ...

//select how many records to show per page
$limit = 10;

//count how many rows 
$total = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagi")->fetchColumn();

if ($total > 0) {
    $start = $limit * $page - $limit;
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagi ORDER BY pg_id LIMIT :start, :limit");
    $sql->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $result['pg_name'],"<br />";
        }
        echo "<hr>";
        paginate($page, $limit, $total);
    }
} else {
    echo "no result to fetch";
}
```

I wasn't entirely sure what you were doing with `$offset` so I changed that bit. Either way, this should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your php, but the .htaccess file. If you want pagi.php in the url, you must change the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/pagi.php/page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /test/pagi.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Tried it just now but it doesn't change my url from `/test/pagi.php?page=1` to `/test/pagi.php/page/1`

Comment: This transformation will work the other way around, changing `/test/pagi.php/page/1` to `/test/pagi.php?page=1`. Is your apache set up with mod_rewrite module?

Comment: Yes my apache is set up with mod_rewrite module